# Copying from one worksheet to another: Application or Object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy from different worksheets to fill out a summary sheet.

I get

> "Application or Object defined error"

```vb
Sub jtest()

'For j = 3 To Rows.Count (will loop later once I make sure one iteration works)
    j = 3     
      
    Atext = Cells(j, "A").Text
    
    Worksheets(Atext).Range("U6").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary 2").Range(j, "C")
    Worksheets(Atext).Range("X6").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary 2").Range(j, "D")
    Worksheets(Atext).Range("Z6").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary 2").Range(j, "F")
    Worksheets(Atext).Range("V7").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary 2").Range(j, "G")
      
'Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: You see how you qualified the `range` with the worksheet `Worksheets(Atext).Range`? Do the same with `cells`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suggest adding `Option Explicit` to the very top, so you're forced to declare variables. Second, you're using `Range()` incorrectly when pasting. Change that to `Cells()` and you're good to go!

```
Sub jtest()
Dim j&, Atext$, lastRow&

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheet("Sheet1").Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row ' CHANGE THAT WORKSHEET AS NECESSARY. I'm also assuming your Column A has the most data.
For j = 3 To lastRow    

    Atext = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "A").Text    ' CHANGE THAT WORKSHEET AS NECESSARY

    Worksheets("Summary 2").Cells(j, "C").Value = Worksheets(Atext).Range("U6").Value
    Worksheets("Summary 2").Cells(j, "D").Value = Worksheets(Atext).Range("X6").Value
    Worksheets("Summary 2").Cells(j, "F").Value = Worksheets(Atext).Range("Z6").Value
    Worksheets("Summary 2").Cells(j, "G").Value = Worksheets(Atext).Range("V7").Value

Next j
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I've edited your idea a tad. Instead of looping over 200,000 times (which would happen if you use `Rows.Count`), I created a `lastRow` variable, assuming your "Sheet1" column A has the most data (edit as necessary).  I've also just set the ranges' values equal, which skips using the Clipboard, and is a little faster.  Note that this will only keep the values, if you need the format, then switch back to `.Copy Destination:= ...` but change your `Range(j, "C")` to `Cells(j, "C")`.

Comment: I know this was not the question, but do you realize the OP is iterating over 1 million times.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yikes, I did not. I've added a second code which (I think) should be a little quicker, no?

Comment: Yes, but I would still find the last row with data in column A, Just to make it that much faster.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ohh! I wasn't thinking at all, and was thinking his `.Rows.Count` was intentional, which I doubt (as you said, that'd loop through a quadrillion cells). Updated code.

Comment: I can see that, but unless the OP has over a million sheets from which he/she is gathering the data I doubt that there is over a million data points.  I may be wrong and the OP may have a million sheets. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of referencing the cells that way, create range objects that reference the cell.  using the example given by above answer, :

```
dim row as range, summaryRow as range, sh as worksheet
set sh = activeworkbook.sheets("Summary 2")
for each row in sh.usedrange.rows 'I prefer to use "usedrange"
```

as you loop through the rows or columns however you are going to do it, set the row that you are using to the row range, same for summary row, and then copy one to the other.

```
row.cells(column).copy summaryRow
```